# Populate memberofdomain list box, i populated the users in the domain, now i want to populate the domains a user is in?

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I have created an application called user extract that communicates with the active directory and extracts user information. A screen shot of my application can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SKhG.jpg 
i am not able to load the actual image here because i need 10 reputations.

i was able to successfully populate the Groups and Users comboBoxes, i was also able to populate my users list box using the following code:

```
 private void fillusersforgroups()
    {

        Users.Items.Clear();
        // string groupname = group.Text();
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any UserPrincipal 
        GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, group.Text);
        if (grp != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal p  in grp.GetMembers(true))
            {
                Users.Items.Add(p.Name + "[" + p.SamAccountName + "]");
            }
            grp.Dispose();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Users In The Above Group");
        }
```

now i want to populate my members of listbox, based of the users comboBox from the above, is there something for users such as getmemebers for groups?? i tried:

```
        private void fillmembersof()
    {

        Groups.Items.Clear();
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any UserPrincipal 
        UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, user.Text);
        if (usr != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal p in usr.GetAuthorizationGroups())
            {
                Groups.Items.Add(p.Name);
            }
            usr.Dispose();
        }

        ctx.Dispose();
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: you are missing and or not displaying code that is relevant to your question.. did you truncate or forget to post the code where you are populating other text boxes..? also you appear to be experiencing a `Scope` issue here I would declare the objects out side of the Method that way you can access them once you instantiate them from within the other methods elsewhere in your existing code..

Comment: also why are you hard coding this ..? `UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "israa");` you need to capture / store the username depending on your logic based on user.Items.Add.. your filmembersof() method creates a new PrincipalContext object therefore you are losing the initial

Comment: @DJKRAZE I added the code that i used to populate my comboBoxes. I did this UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "israa"); to see if i am able to get it by passing a single user at a time, but that didnt work. Thanks Again for trying to help me fix this issue. so u think that .subtree might be causing the issue in scope.

Comment: i fixed it myself, just thought id drop the answer here so it could be useful for others.  (Groups.Items.Clear();
            
         
            // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any UserPrincipal 
            UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
            if (usr != null)
            {
                foreach (var group in usr.GetGroups())
                {
                    Groups.Items.Add(group.Name);
                }

Comment: glad you were able to fix this `+1`